# How do bonds rotate in pericyclic reactions?

Tags: organic-chemistry, physical-chemistry, molecular-orbital-theory, pericyclic, physical-organic-chemistry

In Pericyclic reactions, it is shown that the terminal bonds rotate (conrotation or disrotation) to allow for allignment of the FMO's, thereby forming the sigma bond

[image: Pericyclic bond formation]

However, a detail that most of my textbooks and references miss out on is **how is the double bond rotating about it's axis**? As far as I know, pi bonds are restricted in their rotation which is what gives rise to cis-trans isomerism. If this is the case, how are the bonds rotating about their axis to align the orbitals?

One possibility I can think of is that the double bond is broken before/during rotation, but I haven't seen this explicitly mentioned anywhere. Any insights are appreciated.

Comment: Well, it is a double bond at the start and a single bond at the end. So as the reaction proceeds, this restricted rotation becomes less and less restricted.

Comment: @orthocresol that sounds plausible... Could you provide a more formal answer, preferably with some references/diagrams? I did read [this](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/74105/theoretical-basis-behind-orbital-correlation-diagram-for-pericyclic-reactions?rq=1) related answer of yours, but I couldn't comprehend it or find anything relevant there.

Comment: I don't have a formal answer, sorry, but it seems intuitive to me that as electrons flow out of the old π bonds (to form the new π and σ bonds) the restrictions on rotation decrease. I would guess that it is a continuous process in which the dihedral angle smoothly goes from 0° to 90° as the reaction proceeds. One way to verify this would be computation, but not something I can do now.

Comment: One way to maybe think about this: if the FMO's didn't rotate, the reaction would not proceed and the two double bonds would stay rigidly as it is in the π overlap. But because we are heating up the substrate, the molecule will start becoming excited and therefore, bond breakage will be initiated. So it's more like a case of availability of higher degrees of freedom for the molecular components with increased temperature, which allows such rotatory overlaps to occur. This bond rotation of course breaks the π overlap, but it's entropically favorable as heating is going on

Comment: Do remember that the pi orbitals on the central carbons will be forming a pi bond as the sp2 becomes more like sp3. Personally, how I was taught is that the drawing above is incorrect. There should be no line bonds drawn if you are representing the p-orbitals.